Custom Environment Values and Non-Sendable Errors
I have a following code. I use the Environment(.showMessage) in my SwiftUI view only to show and hide views. When I compile this code with Swift 6 I get the error (shown at the end).
struct ShowMessageAction {
    typealias Action = (String, MessageType) -> ()
    let action: Action
    func callAsFunction(_ message: String, _ messageType: MessageType = .error) {
        action(message, messageType)
    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    @Entry var showMessage = ShowMessageAction { _, _ in }
}

    Static property 'defaultValue' is not concurrency-safe because non-'Sendable' type 'ShowMessageAction' may have shared mutable state. 

What can I do in this situation?
UPDATE 1:
I made the change but now MyProductListScreen is complaining.
      NavigationStack {
//Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous // nonisolated context
                    MyProductListScreen()
                }

MyProductListScreen
    struct MyProductListScreen: View {
        
// It complains about showMessage. 
        @Environment(\.showMessage) private var showMessage
        @Environment(ProductStore.self) private var productStore
        @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
        @AppStorage("userId") private var userId: Int?

SOLUTION:
I ended up marking my destination property in AppScreen with @MainActor.
 @MainActor
    @ViewBuilder
    var destination: some View {
        switch self {
            case .home:
            NavigationStack {
                ProductListScreen()
            }
            case .myProducts:
            NavigationStack {
                MyProductListScreen()
                        .requiresAuthentication()
            }


It's a bad idea to centralise navigation with an enum like that

This is very much related to how the @Entry macro generates the defaultValue property (See also my answer here).
@Entry in your current code generates
static let defaultValue = ShowMessageAction { _, _ in }

which is considered not safe because ShowMessageAction is not Sendable (See also SE-0412).
We would like defaultValue to be a computed property, so there is no global state. i.e.
static var defaultValue: ShowMessageAction { 
    ShowMessageAction { _, _ in } 
}

@Entry can generate this if you specify the type of the property explicitly.
@Entry var showMessage: ShowMessageAction = .init { _, _ in }

It is impossible for @Entry to generate a computed property without an explicit type, because a computed property needs an explicit type annotation, but macros cannot know the type of an arbitrary expression like ShowMessageAction { _, _ in }.

Thanks! So even if I use ShowMessageAction as a struct it is not considered safe due to the static property defaultValue. So it is basicallly due to the static property which can be shared and can cause issues. Your solution allows us to create the computed property which is safe. Thanks for your. help!

@johndoe It's also because ShowMessageAction is not Sendable. If you wrote typealias Action = @Sendable (String, MessageType) -> (), making it Sendable, a static stored property would be totally OK. But of course, making Action a sendable closure has other undesirable consequences :)

Thanks. Now I am facing other issues with MyProductListScreen. I updated the question with the issue.

Yes as soon I put @.MainActor on the destination property it got fixed. Is it just me or all these concurrency checks are just making Swift suck.

@johndoe (not going to start a discussion here so this will be my last comment) I think it's mainly migrating old code that sucks, not strict concurrency checking itself. When I write new code, I feel the concurrency checks can often help me spot concurrency problems very early on, so then I can change the design of things accordingly.

To make something Sendable you have to meet a few conditions

Value types
Reference types with no mutable storage
Reference types that internally manage access to their state
Functions and closures (by marking them with @Sendable)

Your code meets these requirements so you can just mark the value type and the function/closure Sendable.
struct ShowMessageAction: Sendable {
    typealias Action = @Sendable (String, MessageType) -> ()
    let action: Action
    func callAsFunction(_ message: String, _ messageType: MessageType = .error) {
        action(message, messageType)
    }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    @Entry var showMessage = ShowMessageAction { _, _ in }
}

